# AnalysisException: Incompatible return types 'BOOLEAN' and 'STRING' of exprs on running Hive insert query

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I did left outer join between two tables but getting error on running the insert query.

Here is the line of the code throwing exception:

> AnalysisException: Incompatible return types 'BOOLEAN' and 'STRING' of
> exprs 'CAST(A.description AS STRING) = CAST(translate(B.NAME, B.CODE,
> B.NAME) AS STRING)' and 'CAST(A.description AS STRING)'.

Here is the case statement I have used:

```
CASE 
WHEN trim(B.CODE) = trim(A.code) THEN cast(A.description as string)=cast(translate(B.NAME,B.CODE,B.NAME) as string)
ELSE cast(A.description as string)
end as description
```

Please help me in resolving this issue

Comment: cast(A.description as string)=cast(translate(B.NAME,B.CODE,B.NAME) as string)  - this is Boolean type expression  And this is string expression `cast(A.description as string)`. Case should return the same type in all THEN and in ELSE

Comment: Please provide the whole query

Comment: what @leftjoin saying is change your statement to `CASE 
WHEN trim(B.CODE) = trim(A.code) THEN  cast(translate(B.NAME,B.CODE,B.NAME) as string)
ELSE cast(A.description as string)
end as description`

Comment: Error is resolved 
thank you @Koushik Roy